# Paste Files In To A Website (No Flash)

Tags: asp.net, silverlight-4.0

I have been told that I need to create a way for users to copy and paste files in to a website. The requirement is that it can not be flash but it can be Silverlight. It is ok if it is Windows/IE only, and it can not be drag and drop (that would be way too easy, right?), it has to be pasting files.

I'm fairly certain this can not be done. One of the developers here said there must be a way since Sharepoint does it, but I believe they're using the Windows Explorer COM object for that. If that's true the user would have to have some sort of network access to the folder and it is probably crawling with security considerations.

Any ideas on how to support pasting of files in the browser without flash?

Comment: HTML 5 mate. Ive seen some amazing demos of this occuring. Check out the HTML demo sites out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... In Silverlight 4 you could look into the Clipboard object, but I can tell you it only supports text.

You have the Silverlight 4 tag on this question, so I will say I'm pretty sure it's not possible yet.

If I were you I would make a list of all the client-side technologies that are acceptable: Silverlight, Flex, etc and research each one. But those smart client technologies generally don't allow that kind of access for security reasons.

Worst case, you could always build a COM object. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this cannot be done with anything other than the likes of flash/silverlight due to security restrictions.

Telerik do a silverlight one... http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/upload.aspx

And I guess you could develop your own.